# How to pass a struct containing arrays using swig between C and Java?

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, swig

I have got some way with Swig but the above question is a show stopper for me.  I have a fairly complex struct which contains my application data and I need to pass it between C code in the ndroid NDK and Java code at the top level application.

The struct is as follows :

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    x1;
    char        s1[4][16];
    char        s2[4][16];
    char        s3[4][16];
    uint32_t    x2[4];
    } MY_STRUCT;
```

It obviously has an unholy brew of multi-dimensional arrays and structure types and I have tried a few things but nothing works.

I need to be able to set and get values in the arrays in both the Java and C code, can anyone tell me the general strategy I should follow to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Boo

Comment: I guess that three fields named **s1** are caused by copy/paste error

Comment: What happens when you let SWIG parse your code? Does it show errors, or warnings, or crash? I would expect some C++ wrapper code and some Java access code. It will probably be quite readable.

Comment: @Alex Cohen : Yes, corrected, thanks

Comment: Nice, but you did not answer my question. Is it a puzzle, or you want to help others help you solve the problem?

Comment: @Alex Cohen: Yes, I am trying to find out how to achieve my aim.  I have tried many different approaches and they have all failed.  None of them are worth showing here.  I was hoping someone would come alone who has done what I need to do and post a brief howto as to using multi-dimensional arrays in structures in JNI using Swig.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably build your set of accessors:

```
%inline %{
void MY_STRUCT_x1_set(struct MY_STRUCT *obj, uint_16 val) {
   obj->x1 = val;
}
void MY_STRUCT_s1_set(struct MY_STRUCT *obj, int i, int j, char val) {
   obj->s1[i][j] = val;
}
char MY_STRUCT_s2_get(struct MY_STRUCT *obj, int i, int j) {
   return obj->s2[i][j];
}
%}
```

... and so on. This way you can have full access from Java (through the generated wrappers) to your structure.

Note that SWIG does not perform out-of-bounds or other conditions that may be violated by misuse of the wrapper code.